# Can't create database with Symfony 5.1 : could not find driver

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, orm, doctrine

When i do the command php bin/console doctrine:database:create i have these errors :

> In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 126: An exception occurred in driver:
>   could not find driver
>
> In PDOConnection.php line 50: could not find driver
>
> In PDOConnection.php line 46: could not find driver

config/packages/doctrine.yaml

````
    doctrine: dbal:
    # configure these for your database server
    driver: 'pdo_mysql'
    server_version: '5.7'
    charset: utf8mb4
    default_table_options:
        charset: utf8mb4
        collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci```
````

.env

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/symbnb
```

php.ini extensions:

```
xtension=bz2
extension=curl
;extension=dba
;extension=com_dotnet
;extension=enchant
;extension=ffi
extension=fileinfo
;extension=ftp
extension=gd2
extension=gettext
extension=gmp
extension=intl
extension=imap
extension=ldap
extension=mbstring
extension=exif      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=mysqli
;extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=odbc
extension=openssl
;extension=pdo_firebird
extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci
;extension=pdo_odbc
;extension=pdo_pgsql
extension=pdo_sqlite
;extension=pgsql
;extension=phpdbg_webhelper
;extension=shmop

; The MIBS data available in the PHP distribution must be installed.
; See http://www.php.net/manual/en/snmp.installation.php
;extension=snmp

extension=soap
extension=sockets
;extension=sodium
;extension=sqlite3
;extension=sysvshm
;extension=tidy
extension=xmlrpc
extension=xsl
;extension=zend_test
```

PHP 7.4.6 - MySQL 8.0.20 Symfony 5.1 - I use Wamp 3.2.2 - I'm on Windows

I don't understand where these errors come from.

Comment: Your configuration looks good. Can you make sure that you edit the correct `php.ini` by typing this in your terminal `php -i | grep php.ini`

Comment: oh It wasn' t the correct  configuration file lmao
thank you

Comment: oh it's working thank you :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on comments, we figured out that the php.ini used by the PHP CLI is not the same.

> Your configuration looks good. Can you make sure that you edit the
>   correct `php.ini` by typing this in your terminal `php -i | grep php.ini`